# unable to get my emails via graph API

Tags: rest, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the graph api to fetch my emails. and I'm using a postman client, I'm getting the authorize token and sending it to the api as header.

When I run the below query.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

the response that I get is

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
  "id": "someId",
  "businessPhones": [],
  "displayName": "MyName",
  "givenName": "MyFirstName",
  "jobTitle": "MyDesignation",
  "mail": "myEmailAddress",
  "mobilePhone": "MyMobileNumber",
  "officeLocation": "MyWorkLocation",
  "preferredLanguage": null,
  "surname": "MySurName",
  "userPrincipalName": "MyEmailAddress"
}
```

and when I try to run the below query.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages
```

The response that I get is as below.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceNotFound",
    "message": "Resource could not be discovered.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "59a0a25b-67c4-4fe8-8aff-eb035b974a4b",
      "date": "2017-03-10T14:09:13"
    }
  }
}
```

Also tried the below URL to get the emails.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages
```

I get the same response as above.

Finally I tried

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mail
```

Here the response that I got is

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('someRandomId')/mail",
  "value": "myEmailAddress"
}
```

please let me know how can I get my emails shown.

In the portal(https://apps.dev.microsoft.com), I've the below things enabled for this application.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: which account you are using ? AAD account or personal account ?

Comment: @Nan Yu, sorry, I'm not sure of.. Basically i'm using my organization email address... Can you please let me know where can I find, if mine is AAD or Personal account...

Comment: Your account is AAD account like xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com or microsoft account like xx@hotmail.com ,xx@outlook.com ?

Comment: My emails address looks like xxxx@myCompanyName.com,it doesn't look Amy of the email addresses that you mentioned... :-(

Comment: I am also facing the same issue and I am also using xxxx@myCompanyName.com account. Have anybody got any solution regarding this problem